# Attempting to compile through MacOS Terminal: "No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, makefile, terminal, parallel-processing, petsc

I'm trying to compile [this project from DTU](https://github.com/topopt/TopOpt_in_PETSc). This project requires that [PETSc](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/index.html) be installed.

I have installed PETSc to `/Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3/`

I have extracted the zip from GitHub to `/Users/hornymoose/dtu`

The DTU project's `makefile` has the following lines:

```
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/variables
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/rules
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/test
```

In these lines, `{PETSC_DIR}` is to be substituted with the user's PETSc installation directory. Thus, I changed these lines to:

```
include $/Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3/lib/petsc/conf/variables
include $/Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3/lib/petsc/conf/rules
include $/Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3/lib/petsc/conf/test
```

To compile the code, I write `make topopt` in Terminal. Doing so yields:

```
makefile:13: Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3/lib/petsc/conf/variables: No such file or directory
makefile:14: Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3/lib/petsc/conf/rules: No such file or directory
makefile:15: Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3/lib/petsc/conf/test: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `Users/jhutopopt/petsc-3.13.3/lib/petsc/conf/test'.  Stop.
```

I have gone back and manually checked that `Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3/lib/petsc/conf/variables`, `...rules`, and `...test` definitely exist and do not have errors.

Why am I receiving this error? Am I indicating the directory incorrectly in my `makefile`? Is the syntax in the `makefile` incorrect?

I'm  sure there is a simple solution, I'm just very new to working with Terminal in MacOS. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is a `$` in the paths:

```
include $/Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3/lib/petsc/conf/variables
        ^
```

This causes the `/` to be treated as a variable, and expanded to nothing because was never set. Run `make` with option `--warn-undefined-variables` to get a warning on that sort of thing. Perhaps already obvious at this point, but the correct line would be:

```
include /Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3/lib/petsc/conf/variables
```

Rather than manually substituting the PETSC_DIR in the makefile you can provide it through an environment variable (assuming PETSc makefiles aren't bad):

```
export PETSC_DIR=/Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3
make topopt
```

...or:

```
PETSC_DIR=/Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3 make topopt
```

...or pass its value to the make invocation:

```
make topopt PETSC_DIR=/Users/hornymoose/petsc-3.13.3
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas, setting PETSC_DIR as an environment variable worked perfectly - especially because the variables, rules, and test files also reference PETSC_DIR.

Comment: @hornymoose Glad to hear it! :)